# Waiting for setState to finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see from a million other questions that there is a callback that can be used after setState is called.  In fact, I use it in my code example here in my `questionChangeSystemCallback` function.

I'm unsure how to take advantage of this in my situation.  Here is my code (stripped for simplicity sake)

The main flow works like this:  A question changes, it calls it's callback, `questionChangeSystemCallback`.  From there it updates it's value in state.  When done updating it's value, it checks for additional things to do and calls `actionExecuter` as needed.

//note, the part that matters is effectively the forEach loop at the bottom that's within the setState questionsData callback.

```
questionChangeSystemCallback(Q) {
    // updates current state of questionsData, checks for action string, executes any actions

    if (Q == null) {
        console.log("questionChangeSystemCallback required field, question, is null");
    }

    let updatedQuestionData = this.getQuestionDataWithUpdatedValue(Q);

    this.setState({ questionsData: updatedQuestionData }, () => {
    // after state is set, check if there are additional actions needed based on the actionOptions

        if (Q.props.actions) {
            let { actions } = Q.props;
            let qval = Q.state.value;
            let commandString = actions[qval];
            if (commandString) {
                let actionsToDo = commandString.split('&');
                actionsToDo.forEach((action) => {
                    this.actionExecuter(action);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`actionExecuter` does this... basically just a switch statement to call `showTab` with a true or fall element:

```
actionExecuter = (actionString) => {
    let splitActionString = actionString.split('::');
    if (splitActionString.length !== 2) {
        //TODO: Throw error
    }
    switch (splitActionString[0]) {
        case "ShowTab":
            this.showTab(splitActionString[1], true);
            break;
        case "HideTab":
            this.showTab(splitActionString[1], false);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Requested action '" + splitActionString[0] + "' not recognized");
    }
}
```

`showTab` looks like this, effectively adding tabName to `this.state.hiddenTabs` if toShow is true and removing tabName from `this.state.hiddenTabs` if it's false... and then setting the `state.hiddenTabs` to the new array.

```
showTab(tabName, toShow) {

    let newHiddenTabs = this.state.hiddenTabs.slice();
    console.log("After copy: ", newHiddenTabs); 
    let cleanTabName = tabName.replace(/ /g, '');
    if (toShow) {
        // remove all instances from newHiddenTabs
        while (newHiddenTabs.includes(cleanTabName)) {
            let index = newHiddenTabs.indexOf(cleanTabName);
            if (index > -1) {
                newHiddenTabs.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        console.log("After removal: ", newHiddenTabs);
    } else {
        // add tabName to newHiddenTabs
        newHiddenTabs.push(cleanTabName);
        console.log("After addition: ", newHiddenTabs);

    }
    console.log("Before setting state: ", newHiddenTabs);
    this.setState({ hiddenTabs: newHiddenTabs }, ()=> {
        console.log("STATE after setting state: ", this.state.hiddenTabs);
    }
    );
}
```

Using that host of console logs, I'm learning 1) the logic here works and 2) that if I have more than one 'action', and thus showTab gets called twice... only the data from the SECOND call ends up in state.  Further, the render method does not get called afterward.

As an example:

initial `this.state.hiddenTabs = ["WaterQuality","FieldForm","EWI","EDI"]`
I have added a console.log("RENDER") to the top of my render function.
I run, as actions, a `ShowTab(EDI, true)` and a `ShowTab(EWI, false)`.

The following is the output:

```
After copy:  (4) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI", "EDI"]   
**(correct)**

After removal:  (3) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI"]   
**(correct)**

Before setting state:  (3) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI"]   
**(correct)**

After copy:  (4) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI", "EDI"]  
**(nope - same initial state as first time through)**

After addition:  (5) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI", "EDI", "EWI"]  
**(given it's input, correct, but overall wrong)**

Before setting state:  (5) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI", "EDI", "EWI"] 
**(given it's input, correct, but overall wrong)**

RENDER  
**(why are we rendering now... and why only once)**

STATE after setting state:  (5) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI", "EDI", "EWI"]  
**(this is the (erroneous) value from the second time through)**

STATE after setting state:  (5) ["WaterQuality", "FieldForm", "EWI", "EDI", "EWI"] 
**(this is the (erroneous) value from the second time through)**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `setState` calls are getting batched. Depending on where you're calling `setState`, [React will batch them automatically](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and only perform a `render`, once the whole batch is finished.

Problem in your case is probably here:

    `let newHiddenTabs = this.state.hiddenTabs.slice();`

When you have multiple actions, this function gets called multiple times and `react` is batching `setState`. Since the updates where not flushed yet, when it performs this action again, the state isn't updated yet!

My suggestion: Extract this to another function and use the other `setState` signature, which takes a function with `prevState` and `props` as argument.
It'd look somewhat like this:

```js
showTab(tabName, toShow) {
  const processTabs = (hiddenTabs) => {
      let cleanTabName = tabName.replace(/ /g, '');
      if (toShow) {
        hiddenTabs = hiddenTabs.filter((tab) => tab !== cleanTabName)
      } else {
        hiddenTabs.push(cleanTabName)
      }
      return hiddenTabs;
  }

  this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ hiddenTabs: processTabs([...prevState.hiddenTabs])}), () => {
    console.log("STATE after setting state: ", this.state.hiddenTabs);
  })
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry, accidentally sent the answer incomplete before D:

Comment: Do you have a good resource on where I could learn about this type of setState call?  I tried modifying it, even in the slightest, and it all falls apart.